# Document has been altered or corruped since the Signature was applied itext 5.5.11

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

Basically I get the error Document has been altered or corruped since the Signature was applied, I followed the example of itext website and adapted to my situation.

- Prepare the document to be signed, add append mode because it can be
  a already signed document
- Called the webservice to sign the hash
- added signed hash to prepared document

I ran out of ideas and hope I can get some help
here's a snippet of my code:

```
    public static final String src = "DynamicClient\sample.pdf";
    public static final String temp= "DynamicClient\sampleTEMP.pdf";
    public static final String dest= "DynamicClient\sampleFINAL.pdf";

    public static void emptySignatureSVC(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            reader.setAppendable(true);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0',null,true);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
            appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, fieldname);
            appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
            ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
            MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
            reader.close();
            
        }

    public static void createSignatureSVC(String src, String dest, String fieldname, byte[] sign, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
            
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(sign, chain);
            MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                Certificate[] chain = signWS.getChain();//External WS to get chain
                emptySignatureSVC(src, temp, "signature", chain);               
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(temp));
                PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);
                byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
                byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CADES);
                
                byte[] extSignature = signWS(sh);//External WS to sign
                sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, "RSA");
    
                createSignatureSVC(temp, dest, "signature", sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash,null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CADES), chain);
}
```

and here are the files:
[original one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVP77ZA7ysCRInf1ddKBmJjOhNZPwPjc/view?usp=sharing)
[Signed one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NvY2LukwL2WoA3nkayWxAOoB89hlndoK/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT:**
Forgot to add the container I use:

```
class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    protected byte[] sig;
    protected Certificate[] chain;
    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig,Certificate[] chain) {
        this.sig = sig;
        this.chain=chain;
    }
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is)throws GeneralSecurityException  {
        
        return sig;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Comment: **A** you hash the wrong data; you hash the whole prepared pdf while you have to hash the prepared pdf except the placeholder for the signature container to inject. **B** are you sure you will need deferred signing?

Comment: **A**. thanks for the fast reply, I'm a bit newbie on the topic.
I though I was signing the wrong data
Do you have any example on how can I produce the correct hash?
**B** - Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- you're hashing the wrong data and
- you're signing incorrectly.

#### Hashing the wrong data

You are hashing the whole prepared PDF like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(temp));
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);
byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
```

This is not correct.

A signed PDF essentially has this structure (read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for more details):

[image]

*(By the way, the sketch is not 100% correct as the angled bracket delimiters '<' and '>' around the signature value must also not be hashed.)*

Your prepared PDF at `temp` has the same structure, merely the "signature value" is not yet an actual signature value but instead a placeholder of 8192 hex-encoded zero bytes (8192 because that's the number you gave in `MakeSignature.signExternalContainer`).

As you can see in the sketch, though, the signature value (or in your case, the placeholder) must not be hashed for signing.

You can calculate the hash using the data returned by `PdfSignatureAppearance.getRangeStream` after the `MakeSignature.signExternalContainer` as proposed by @LkbhaiLr in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776866/1729265).

Alternatively you can use (instead of the `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer`) a custom `ExternalSignatureContainer` implementation which in its `sign` method simply hashes its `InputStream` parameter and provides that hash.

I'd prefer the latter approach but the former approach also is in wide use.

#### Signing incorrectly

You retrieve the naked signature value like this:

```
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CADES);
byte[] extSignature = signWS(sh);//External WS to sign
```

I.e. you forward the attributes structure as is to your signing service and expect it to create a proper signature value for it.

Inspecting your [signed example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NvY2LukwL2WoA3nkayWxAOoB89hlndoK/view?usp=sharing), though, it becomes clear that that signing service does not live up to your expectations: Instead of *signing* with SHA256withRSA, it merely *encrypts* with RSA and PKCS#1 padding. Thus, it expects you to do half the signing for you, i.e. hashing with SHA256 and building a `DigestInfo` structure.

Thus, before calling `signWS` you have to hash that attributes structure returned by `sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` and then wrap the resulting hash value in a `DigestInfo` object.

As you calculate hashes elsewhere, that shouldn't be an issue for you. And for wrapping a hash in a `DigestInfo` [RFC 8017 section 9.2 note 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) offers a short cut:

> For the nine hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER encoding T of the `DigestInfo` value is equal to the following:
>
> ```
> ...
> SHA-256: (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20 || H.
> ...
> ```

I.e. you only have to prefix your hash with the byte sequence `30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
Manage to sign with what u said :)

Comment: @JoaoBenevides Great !

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```java
public static final String src = "DynamicClient\sample.pdf";
public static final String temp= "DynamicClient\sampleTEMP.pdf";
public static final String dest= "DynamicClient\sampleFINAL.pdf";

public byte[] emptySignatureSVC(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    reader.setAppendable(true);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0',null,true);
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, fieldname);
    appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
    InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();  
    
    BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    
    reader.close();
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(inp, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
     
    return hash;
}

public byte[] signed_hash(byte[] hash, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", "SunPKCS11-eToken");
    BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
    System.out.println(hashAlgorithm);
    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);

    byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);

    System.out.println(signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
    sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
    return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}

public static void createSignatureSVC(String src, String dest, String fieldname, byte[] sign, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(sign, chain);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {
    byte[] hh = emptySignatureSVC(src, temp, "sig1", chain);
    byte[] hh_sign = (app.signed_hash(hh,  pk,  chain));
    createSignatureSVC(temp, dest, "sig1",hh_sign,  chain);
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried this approach before and still get the same error

Comment: @JoaoBenevides At first glance that code looks ok. Can you share a sample file signed using the approach from this answer for analysis?

Comment: @JoaoBenevides Ah, I could see the error already in your original signature.

Comment: @mkl sure, I did a few changes on the signed_hash to call the WS to sign since I don't use/have acess the the private key
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RG9fdA4jY66bsWi7-ZIdTTDXSMUdibSq/view?usp=sharing] (signed doc)

Comment: @JoaoBenevides Compare my answer, of the two issues mentioned there you apparently for this file have fixed issue #1, so you only have to fix issue #2.